# Javascript functions don't work after MVC Upgrade

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have upgraded a solution from MVC 3 to MVC 4.

I have 2 specific JavaScript functions that does not work anymore after upgrade.

1. Tabs

This is how the tabs now render

[image: Tab Rendering]

I suspect it has to do with the JavaScript version with the new framework? I am not sure.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $('.taberize').each(function () {
        var e = $(this);
        var panels = e.parents('.ui-tabs-panel');
        if (panels.length == 0) { return; }
        var tabId = $(panels[0]).attr('id');
        e.attr('href', e.attr('href') + '#' + tabId);
    });

    $(".container").each(function (e) {
        var height = $(document).height() - 230;
        $(this).height(height);
    });
});
```

---

2. On Row Hover function

The On-Row-Hover function does not work anymore, I have a "Action Menu" on the left side of my WebGrid, and on row hover, it display functions like Edit and Details menu... this is done in JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prevRow = null;
            $('#gridData table tbody tr').not(':first').hover(function()
            {
                $('#myMenu').hide();
                    if (prevRow != this)
                    {

                        if (prevRow != null)
                        {
                            $(prevRow).css("background","");
                            $('.actionButtons', $(prevRow)).hide(); 
                        }                       

                        $(this).css("background","#EDEFFF");
                        $('.actionButtons', $(this)).show();
                        prevRow = this;          
                    }
            },
            function()
            {
                    if (!$('#myMenu').is(":visible"))
                    {
                        if (prevRow != null)
                        {
                            $(prevRow).css("background","");
                            $('.actionButtons', $(prevRow)).hide(); 
                            prevRow = null;
                        }
                    }
            });

           $(".openmenu").contextMenu({ menu: 'myMenu', leftButton: true }, 
           function(action, el, pos) {
                contextMenuWork(action, el.parents('tr')[0].id , pos);

           });

           function contextMenuWork(action, id) {
            switch (action) {

                case "insert":
                    {
                     if($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version.substr(0,1)<8){var url='@Url.Action("Create", "Account")';document.location=url}else{CreateNewAccount()}
                      break;
                    }
                case "createtask":
                    {
                        var url = '@Url.Action("CreateFromAccount", "UserTask")' + '/' + id;
                        document.location = url;
                        break;
                    }
                case "linkassessment":
                    {
                       var url = '@Url.Action("CreateFromAccount", "Questionnaire")' + '/' + id;
                       document.location = url;
                       break;
                    }
                case "details":
                    {
                        var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Account")' + '/' + id;
                        document.location = url;
                        break;
                    }  
                case "edit":
                    {
                      var url = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Account")' + '/' + id;
                      document.location = url;
                      break;
                    }
              case "createperson":
                    {
                        if($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version.substr(0,1)<8){var url='@Url.Action("Create", "Person")';document.location=url}else{CreateNewPerson(id)}
                        break;
                    }
               case "createopportunity":
                    {
                      var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "Opportunity")' + '/' + id;
                      document.location = url;
                      break;
                    }  

             }

      }

        }); 
</script>

<div id="gridData">
            <ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu" style="display: none">
                <li class="insert"><a href="#insert" id="create">Create New</a></li>
                <li class="detail"><a href="#details">Details</a></li>
                <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th class="field-actions-account" style="width: 75px">
                        <a href="#">Actions</a>
                    </th>
<tr id="@Html.Encode(item.AccountID)">
                        <td>
                        <div class="actionButtons" style="display:none">
                             <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.AccountID }) " style="text-decoration:none" title="Edit"><img src="@Html.Raw(@Url.Content("~/Content/img/document-pencil-icon.png"))" alt="Edit" title="Edit" style="border:none"/> </a>
                             <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.AccountID }) " style="text-decoration:none" title="Details"><img src="@Html.Raw(@Url.Content("~/Content/img/testDetailsIcon.gif"))" alt="Details" title="Details" style="border:none" /> </a>
                             <img src="@Html.Raw(@Url.Content("~/Content/img/options.gif"))" alt="More Options" class="openmenu" title="More Options"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Open F12 Developer tools in browser and see if there are any errors? Also check if you are referring the JQuery JS file in layout?

Comment: are you using @RenderSection in your layout?

Comment: @pooriataghizadeh, I do use "@RenderSection":  "@RenderSection("Head", false)"

Comment: @ramiramilu, 1 Error: Uncaught TypeError: a(...).on is not a function in file "jquery.validate.min.js"

Comment: Does your JQuery code is in Section like - `@section Head { ... }`? And do you have - `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")`?

Comment: no, I don't have a Section for JQuery nor Scripts.Render.  I am new to MVC4, can you assist in how this should look? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your javascript code in section like this:

```
  @section Head
  {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $('.taberize').each(function () {
      var e = $(this);
      var panels = e.parents('.ui-tabs-panel');
      if (panels.length == 0) { return; }
      var tabId = $(panels[0]).attr('id');
      e.attr('href', e.attr('href') + '#' + tabId);
    });

    $(".container").each(function (e) {
       var height = $(document).height() - 230;
       $(this).height(height);
      });
    });
   </script>
  }
```

then be sure your "@RenderSection("Head", false) is under your @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") in your layout like this :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("Head", false)
```

and finally check your BundleConfig class has a code like this  file :

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
             "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pooria, I have made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, somehow the jquery.validate file has been modified, and that was causing my problem.

Comment: only FireFox has still the issue... will see what the problem can be